# Will Asio or Boost.Asio work on iPhone or Android?

Tags: android, c++, iphone, boost, boost-asio

Can Asio or Boost.Asio be used in iPhone or Android development? I'm considering using it so I don't need to use different network libraries for each of my targeted platforms.

Comment: for iPhone development, this question has already been asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577838/how-to-build-boost-libraries-for-iphone

Comment: Do you want to write native apps for android?

Comment: my plan just now is to get a working code in Windows (mobile and desktop) using Boost Asio. Then I would like to cross-compile the same source to iPhone. Then hopefully not require a lot of code changes to compile the same source in Android.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Asio for both.

Comment: yes. it works really well on ios and android. just that you have to compile asio for both the platforms

Answer (score -3):

You should abstract your Network Classes to use the one provided by the APIs

Comment: it would be better if you can be more descriptive about you are to trying to explain.